# WCF - Callback and/or Event

Tags: wcf, events, callback

How can I receive a message from one client and Callback to all Clients connected to the Host to send that message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a "publish-and-subscribe" service - there's a number of ways you can achieve this in WCF - see those blog posts and articles for more information:

- [Building your own ESB - Publish / Subscribe](http://www.iserviceoriented.com/blog/post/Building+Our+Own+ESB+-+Publish+Subscribe+Part+1.aspx)
- [Using Callback Contracts in WCF for Asynchronous Publish/Subscribe Event-Style Communication](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm)
- [Design Patterns: List-Based Publish-Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx)
- [Windows Azure – Service Bus Publish/Subscribe Example](http://itechthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/windows-azure-service-bus-publishsubscribe-example/)

Marc